# How to use a regex to remove some illegal characters from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to remove characters `&%*@()!{}` from a string. I tried this code:

```
keyword.gsub!(/[\&\%\*\@\(\)\!\{\}]/, '')`
```

but it failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regex isn't right. It appears you don't understand how `[...]` works in a regex.

You can use:

```
gsub(/[&%*@()!{}]+/, '')
```

For instance:

```
'foo&%*@()!{}bar'.gsub(/[&%*@()!{}]+/, '') # => "foobar"
```

An alternate way to do this, without using a regex is to use the [`tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr) method:

```
'foo&%*@()!{}bar'.tr('&%*@()!{}', '') # => "foobar"
```

The benefit of using `tr`, AKA "translate" is it doesn't take a regex, and can do deletions, like here, or translations from one character to another. It's also very fast.

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bm() do |b|

  b.report { n.times { 'foo&%*@()!{}bar'.gsub(/[&%*@()!{}]+/, '') } }
  b.report { n.times { 'foo&%*@()!{}bar'.tr('&%*@()!{}', '')   } }

end
```

Returns on my machine running 1.9.3-p362:

```
   user     system      total        real
4.120000   0.010000   4.130000 (  4.125929)
1.280000   0.000000   1.280000 (  1.282932)
```

Comment: That benchmark difference is pretty interesting. With ruby 1.8.7, I see 1.21 and 0.9. Under ruby 1.9.2, I see 1.67 and 0.88 and roughly the same for 1.9.3. I wonder why your values for `gsub` differ so much?

Comment: Don't know. I'm on 1.9.3-p362, and, running it several times shows consistent results on my system. The important thing is, `tr` is faster than `gsub` when doing deletes or changes of single characters.

Comment: @theTinMan: Your `tr` function is wrong. It removes `[]+`, which are not invalid character according to OP's question.

Comment: You're right. I copied the same line for `gsub` to `tr`. It's an easy fix.

Comment: @JimSchubert: a hypothesis: 1.9 uses Oniguruma, a much more powerful regexp engine. Power usually comes at a loss of speed, so might be related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transliterate from I18n:

```rb
require 'i18n'

I18n.transliterate(keyword).scan(/\w+[a-zA-Z0-9]/).join(' ')
```

Transliterate will remove the accent of the word and the regex will only collect chars in that range, and in the end the "join" will concatenate the words with space between them.